# Java - FileNotFoundException in terminal

Tags: java

this method that I have runs prefectly in eclipse

```
public boolean verifyAdminLoginCredentials(String keyboardInputUsername, String keyboardInputPassword) {
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("adminInfo.txt"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                usernameInFile = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
                passwordInFile = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
                if((keyboardInputUsername.equals(usernameInFile) && (passwordHSHA256(keyboardInputPassword).equals(passwordInFile)))) {
                    isLogin = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return isLogin;
}
```

But when i compiled all my java files and run in my macbook terminal. It is throwing me a error
that the program can't find the file

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: adminInfo.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at UserAccount.verifyAdminLoginCredentials(UserAccount.java:97)
```

Why is this so? Please help

Comment: Well presumably the file doesn't exist in the directory that you're running it from. How are you running the program, and *does* the file exist?

Comment: yes the file existed.

Comment: where does the file exist?

Comment: That doesn't answer how you're running the program. Please add all the information into the question.

Comment: You may want to use the Fully qualified name of the file.

Comment: 1. my textfile is in /Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram and all my java file is in  /Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram/src.                                       2. I javac *.java the files in  /Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram/src

Comment: 3. How did you execute? java ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the file `adminInfo.txt` is not in the directory that you are running your program from. To find your current directory type `pwd` and to see the files in that directory use the command `ls`. If you want to specify a file to read that is not in your programs directory, you have to specify a full path (i.e. replace `adminInfo.txt` with `"/Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram/adminInfo.txt"`)

You want:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram/adminInfo.txt"));
```

instead of

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("adminInfo.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the directory you are running from in your Terminal?

```
$ pwd
/my/dir
$ ls
MyClass.java MyClass.class adminInfo.txt
```

Make sure when you list your directory, the `adminInfo.txt` file is present. Otherwise, your might need to change your directory layout. Usually, in eclipse you have something like this:

```
Project
   /src (sources {.java} files here)
   /bin (binaries {.class} files here)
   adminInfo.txt
```

So, when you run your application within Eclipse, the `./bin` is automatically added to your classpatch.

So, if you go in your terminal to your project directory, you might try this:

```
$ cd MY_PROJECT_DIR
$ java -cp ./bin MyClass
```

UPDATE: now I know the directory name.

Try this:

```
$ cd /Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram
$ java -cp ./bin PUT_THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS_HERE
```

Comment: I placed the textfile in  /Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram

Answer (score 0):

When executing from Eclipse, a file with a relative path name (ie. it does not beging with a '/') is below the root directory of your Eclipse project. But if you execute from a terminal, the same relative path points to a place in and below the "working directory". Use `pwd` to see this directory and `cd <pathname>` to change it.

After

```
javac *.java
```

in /Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram/src, enter the command

```
cd ..
```

and then execute using

```
java -cp src xxx
```

where xxx is whatever you used before after running `java`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("adminInfo.txt"));
```

with

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/gerard/Documents/workspace/sampleprogram/adminInfo.txt"));
```

ie with fully qualified name of the file.

If still exception comes, you're in trouble.